# Is there a way to catch the "cannot open display $DISPLAY" exception?

Tags: gtk, x11, gtkmm

I'm creating a gtk app like this:

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app;
try {
    app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "loocal.testgtk",
        Gio::APPLICATION_HANDLES_COMMAND_LINE);
}
catch (...) {
    ....
}
```

If the X server isn't there (isn't reachable) the process is aborted, the `catch(...)` part is never executed.

Q: Is there a way prevent abort and to catch this exception - and e.g. retry or connect to a fall-back display?

Also: Is there a way to catch the exception when the connection with the X server breaks - in order to (try to) restart the GUI part of the application and reconnect to the X server or to a fall-back X server?

Answer (score 2):

The default is to simply call `exit(1)` if the display cannot be opened.

If you want to override this, do the following before anything else. Call `gtk_init_check()`, then `gdk_display_open()` and `gdk_display_manager_set_default_display()`.